# Symfony2 Add multiples images to an entity. The clean way

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, doctrine-orm, file-io

My question is more an architecture question than a real problem.

> ***MODEL***

At this moment I have one entity and a collection of images (Image entity) attached to them (@ManyToMany).

> ***VIEW***

Actually I have some stable code running on production but it's nightmare to maintain.
I'm using Js and Ajax. Js is listening for a fake multiple input and sending the images to Symfony. At this point Symfony2 is creating a fake temporarily folder and adding inside the images (huge piece of code).

I don't think this can't run properly without ajax and js (remember than we can't change the input file value) and I am also using a layout box if the user want to drag ad drop images instead of adding it manually.

> ***CONTROLLER***

After the real form is submitted, the controller is checking for files inside this temporarily folder and adding it to the images collection of the entity (I don't think this is the right approach) and moving the images from the temp folder to an S3 box.

> ***QUESTION***

Any idea to manage this problem in a different way? Probably avoiding storing the images in a temp folder or/and using properly the Symfony2 forms and the Doctrine Listeners / postUpdate-postPersist.

Comment: Is there any specific reason for having the temp folder? I mean why not directly moving the files to their final destination on submit?

Comment: I'm adding this images to a temp folder because if the user won't to submit the form with that I'm able to remove the temp folder any 1 day. (another reason to remove this shit)

Comment: That makes sense. So I would suggest to keep the path of each image in some temp places (e.g. Session, Cache, DB Temp Table, ...) Though if the form is submitted successfully you can just grab the file path and move each one to the right place. If the user did not submit the form the temp Session, Cache or other temp destination will be expired. If you agree let me know to put on the answer

Comment: Do you think this is the only/better/clean way to do that?

Comment: I just suggested; there might be some other way to implement; but it was the first thing came to my mind

Comment: Which kind of path do you want to store in the Session/Cache/DB Temp Table? The image path in temp folder? I think I'm gonna still have the same problem following your answer

Comment: Yes, it seems to have same issue, but this will reduce your code because now you are doing double work (saving temp files in another temp folder)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been through this problem before and there is no way around it: if you want to upload images asynchronously (AJAX), at some point you are gonna have to store them in some sort of temporal folder. This creates the well-known problem when the user uploads something but doesn't complete the rest of form and just leaves the page. You need some sort of mechanism to remove "orphaned" images, which does not belong to any completed request and are just sitting there in the temp folder.

There is a bundle that I have been using extensively, which allows exactly this. It provides an easy way of handling file uploads using whatever AJAX solution you need (or making your own), and also provides a nice file system abstraction (which you can use to store your images in your S3 bucket). But the coolest feature is the `orphanage`, that let you clean temp uploaded but not used images by just running a command. Then it is just a matter of doing a cron with this command to clean the folder regularly.

This is the bundle: https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle

You can integrate this easily with Symfony, just take into account that you are gonna have 2 actions, one to upload the images asynchronously (which can be a form or not), and another one to process the real form. Putting both of them together is trivial, just make sure you keep track of the temporal uploaded images, using sessions, filesystem folder, or a table in a database.

Comment: There is other way to to this synchronously (without ajax)? I don't think so

Comment: There is, you can create a `file` input with the `multiple` option and add it to your form, or create multiple `file` input and let the user select one by one. Doing it synchronously doesn't give you headaches about orphaned files and so, but at a great cost in application's clumsiness. Anyway, you are gonna have to support it sooner or later for legacy browsers, like IE.

Comment: The problem with that is losing old selections from the input multiple. There is no way to add this files again in the sent post data.

Comment: That's why in the tutorial and official documentation they usually use 2 fields in the entity, one for the filename stored in the database and another one to upload the file using the form. Then it's just a matter of copying one to the other after the form is submitted and validated. Check this out: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html

Answer (score 0):

I also came across this problem and as Alberto said, there's no work-around.

Instead of moving the files in a temp folder, I move them in the right folder far away. Then of course there is the problem of non-used stored files because obviously the files are gonna be uploaded even if the user doesn't end up the the whole form.

Personally I very dislike this approach as well, I solved it building a function that deletes non-used files on the server which I run daily by a cron job.

```
0 0 * * * /usr/local/bin/php /path/to/symfonyproject/Tasks/CleanFiles.php
```

In my opinion, this is dirty, and after driving me nuts, I figured out there aren't other options.

Comment: I agree with you. But I think this is the only option. Can't imagine software like facebook doing stuff like that.